# .net Dictionary.Resize() exception - thread safety?

Tags: .net, dictionary, c#-3.0, thread-safety

We have a very serious problem that's causing thousands of exceptions per minute. We've got a website that runs a home-grown caching mechanism that holds data in the form of:

```
protected static IDictionary<int, IList<IInterfaceForData>> m_Data = null;
```

and when we call Add on this dictionary, we get a very bizarre behavior: "**Index was outside the bounds of the array**", when the key was 100% not in the dictionary:

```
m_Data.Add(id, new List<IInterfaceForData>());
```

We protect this call using a lock like this:

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(m_LockObj, 1000))
{
   try
   {
       m_Data.Add(id, new List<IInterfaceForData>());
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {                                   
        // log exception
   }
   finally
   {
      Monitor.Exit(m_LockObj);
   }
}
```

and we get this exception:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize()     at   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

We can't find any explanation for this because the exception is related to Dictionary's thread safety, and we (think we) are thread safe. We use lock() or Monitor.TryEnter on every Add() and Remove() calls, except for m_Data.TryGetValue(...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks a lot.

Comment: You will have to lock on `TryGetValue`, too, and anything else that reads or updates the dictionary. `TryGetValue` tends to behave unpredictably when some other thread adds or removes an item concurrently.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing `TryGetValue` on the *generic* dictionary with `TryGetValue` on the *concurrent* dictionary, since they were both introduced fairly recently (.NET 3.5 and .NET 4).

Comment: @Justin: Wha? `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue` has been around forever!

Comment: @DanTao - Whoops, guess I was just confused by the "Other Versions" dropdown on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx

Comment: @Jim, locking on TryGetValue will change the code to Single Reader and I want it to be MultiReader.

Comment: @Nir: Use `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.  That allows N readers or 1 writer.

Comment: @Nir did you find any solution that works for 2.0/3.5 framework ? I am facing same problem and I can't upgrade to 4.0

Comment: @Imran - no I didn't. We upgraded to 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like at some point the code is not locked and the collection is changed... Have you taken a look at the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace? Specifically the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class? It is thread safe and will probably save you from lots of pains of weird bugs like that or race conditions, etc

It works almost like the regular dictionary , except that for most operations you use a "try" method ie `TryGetValue` this will try to get the value and return `True` if the operation was valid and `False` if not, you can then of course check against this values to continue with your logic

You should check-out this msdn link, its really similar to what you are doing:

[Implementing a cache with ConcurrentDictionary](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/37bbc361-6851-43db-9e90-80cc7e6ac15f)

the asker is currently using a non-concurrent dictionary with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and is changing it to a concurrent dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, but we write in .net 3.5. ConcurrentDictionary is in .net 4.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be synchronizing access to your `m_Data` dictionary *everywhere*, not just the `Add` calls. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, everywhere except when calling m_Data.TryGetValue(...), Remove() and Add() calls are either using lock() or Monitor.TryEnter(). thanks!

Comment: @Nir: As Jim Mischel pointed out in a comment, it isn't good enough to only lock on writes. You have to lock on reads, too; otherwise the collection may be modified *in the middle of* a read operation.

Comment: locking on TryGetValue will change the code to Single Reader and I want it to be MultiReader.

Comment: @Nir: Then you're using the wrong class. A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` can only support multiple concurrent readers *when it isn't being written to*. If you don't synchronize your `TryGetValue` call(s) with your writes, then all bets are off. If you're on .NET 3.5, I'd recommend downloading the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) library and using the backported `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class from that.